# Динамическое изменение title через Javascript.

Tags: javascript, php

Есть тайтл

> `<title>[#title#]</title>`

сюда выносится переменная из недр CMS. Результат заголовка, например такой:

> `Эта страница с информацией`

Требуется добавить в тайтл даты. Что бы было так:

> Эта страница с информацией за
> Январь-Февраль 2014 года

В title js код не исполнить. Есть же document.title.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var d=new Date();
var month=new Array(12);
month[0]="Январь";
month[1]="Февраль";
month[2]="Март";
month[3]="Апрель";
month[4]="Май";
month[5]="Июнь";
month[6]="Июль";
month[7]="Август";
month[8]="Сентябрь";
month[9]="Октябрь";
month[10]="Ноябрь";
month[11]="Декабрь";
document.write(month[d.getMonth()]); </script> <script type="text/javascript">
var y = new Date();
document.write(y.getUTCFullYear());
</script>
```

Этот код добывает месяц + год.
А как сделать "Месяц-След.месяц- год" и все это добавить в конец title?
Может есть решение на php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На js как-то так:

```
(function() {
var d=new Date(),
    months="Январь Февраль Март Апрель Май Июнь Июль Август Сентябрь Октябрь Ноябрь Декабрь".split(' '),
    start_month=months[d.getMonth()],
    start_year=d.getFullYear();
d.setMonth(d.getMonth()+1) //тут хитрость - если больше 11 - то это дата следующего года....
var end_month=months[d.getMonth()],end_year=d.getFullYear();
if (end_year!=start_year) { //чтобы вывести год возле периода декабрь-январь
    start_month+=' '+start_year;
} 
console.log('Эта страница с информацией за '+start_month+' - '+end_month+' '+end_year);
document.title='Эта страница с информацией за '+start_month+' - '+end_month+' '+end_year;
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YDELR/

http://run.plnkr.co/aEPz9ILUkRE6XcQ1/

Comment: БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО!